# C# Google Pay for Passes transit ticket loading error

Tags: c#, rest, google-pay

We're trying to integrate with Google Pay for Passes to add transit tickets to Google Pay, using C# and the "skinny" flow as described here:
["Skinny" JWT variation](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/introduction/typical-api-flows#skinny-jwt)

We're also using the C# example as provided here:  [google-pay/passes-rest-samples](https://github.com/google-pay/passes-rest-samples)

The REST calls for transit all succeed and the JWT token is generated, however when trying to add the ticket to Google Pay by using the link "https://pay.google.com/gp/v/save/{jwt_generated}" it just fails with a generic error saying "Something went wrong. Please try again later.". We've tried by just using the link directly, by adding a JS button on a website and even tried loading from a native android application, they all come back with the same error. When using JS button, the error callback returns "SERVICE_ERROR" with no further details. On google console we can see the transit class status as APPROVED.

Any details on what we might be missing would be helpful as it's not clear where the problem is originating from.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm hitting the exact same problem - returning 'SERVICE_ERROR' which isn't documented.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to help you out here. But the best course of action is to request support with the following URL: https://support.google.com/pay/merchants/contact/instore_merchants

The team should be able to look into your specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue using passes-rest-samples.
I've missed changing SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS in Config.cs, so resolved it by changing it to right service account.

this.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS = "ServiceAccountEmail@developer.gserviceaccount.com"; // CHANGEME

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).